# Android list view adapter hiccup

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

So I have noticed something weird in Android List Adapters.

I have an adapter that is inflated with lets say template.xml, this template has a text view (TextView1 default: "hello"). In some cases TextView1 must have a value of "not now" and in other cases nothing (ie the default should be displayed). When the list contains all the default values everything is ok.

But as soon as in the GetView of a specific adapter I change it to "not now" it effects the others as well (not always if I close the activity and reopen it it may work).

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior happens as intended.

The adapter recycles views through the use of convertView, which means that, for example, a view that you returned on position 10 can be reused on position 19.

For example:
If you set your position 10 to be "not now", and didn't change it back to the default value in your getView method in the position 19, it will keep the value you set for position 10.

Comment: Ahh I see, so just to be sure I should always refill very textview in that view.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without your code, but this looks like a problem with reused views.

Make sure that you put back to default or to custom text every view in 'getView'. If you do not change it, it will leave the value that was previously set, which might not be the default one.